# How to make a function apply to specific woocommerce shop categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the following code to make WooCommerce display only the minimum price for variable products in my shop and also to append the unit (per metre). But I also sell some regular products and I don't want price 'per metre' displayed for them.

How can I modify the code to apply only to certain product categories?

Also, how would you display the 4th price in the array (from minimum to maximum) rather than the 1st (minimum)?

```
// Hide Price Range for WooCommerce Variable Products
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 
'lw_variable_product_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 
'lw_variable_product_price', 10, 2 );

function lw_variable_product_price( $v_price, $v_product ) {

// Product Price
$prod_prices = array( $v_product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), 
                            $v_product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
$prod_price = $prod_prices[0]!==$prod_prices[1] ? sprintf(__('%1$s per metre.', 'woocommerce'), 
                       wc_price( $prod_prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prod_prices[0] );

// Regular Price
$regular_prices = array( $v_product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), 
                          $v_product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
sort( $regular_prices );
$regular_price = $regular_prices[0]!==$regular_prices[1] ? sprintf(__('%1$s per metre.','woocommerce')
                      , wc_price( $regular_prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $regular_prices[0] );

if ( $prod_price !== $regular_price ) {
$prod_price = '<del>'.$regular_price.$v_product->get_price_suffix() . '</del> <ins>' . 
                       $prod_price . $v_product->get_price_suffix() . '</ins>';
}
return $prod_price;
}
```

Comment: Use `get_the_terms` to get the product's categories, and then base your decision on what that returns ...

Comment: _"Also, how would you display the 4th price in the array (from minimum to maximum) rather than the 1st (minimum)?"_ - by using the index `3` instead of `0`...?

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. An example of how to use get_the_terms would be useful! I tried replacing all 0's in the code above with 3, but then got a price of $0. When I changed the 1's to 3's nothing changed at all.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/ - product id as first parameter, `product_cat` for the taxonomy.

Comment: _"I tried replacing all 0's in the code above with 3, but then got a price of $0."_ - seeing how you created $prod_prices, that appears to only have two entries - one for the minimum variation price, and one for the maximum.

Comment: I didn't write the code above. I just found it online and am trying to adapt it to my needs (with little to no coding ability!)

$product->get_variation_prices() fetches all the prices, but how do I access the 4th one only?

Comment: According to documentation, the return value is an _"Array of RAW prices, regular prices, and sale prices with keys set to variation ID."_ - so you can't go `[3]` directly - but if you use `array_values` on the result first, it should work fine (because that resets the array to use a zero-based numeric index.)